# How can I apply a media query to height and width using Tailwind?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to do something like this with Tailwind,

```
@/media screen and (max-width: 995px) , screen and (max-height: 700px) { ... }
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 21):

Solved with:

```
screens: {
    'custombp': {'raw': '(max-height: 1234px),(min-width:920px)'}
}
```

<sub>*Added on behalf of question asker.*</sub>

Comment: This feels like dumb syntax on Tailwind's part since vanilla CSS uses `and` and `and` should be there because `raw` implies it just blindly pastes it into the output with `@media` prepended...

Comment: The code you provided acts as a logical `or` not a logical `and`

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this specific problem, you can do like this,

`screens: { 'custom-height-mq': { 'raw': '((max-width: 995px) and (max-height: 700px))' }, }`

Similarly, you can apply any media query. You can use other logical operators as well and, or etc.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, you can use `raw` to create granular breakpoints based on both height and width, here's a link to the relevant docs which I was only able to find after reading the above answers:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens#custom-media-queries

Answer (score -11):

In your tailwind config .js file you can add something like this. Follow the [breakpoints](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/breakpoints/#app) link, there are other examples to study from.

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      'sm': '640px',
      // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }

      'md': '768px',
      // => @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

      'lg': '1024px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }

      'xl': '1280px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1280px) { ... }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer what the poster was asking, which was how to add multiple media breakpoints together in the tailwind config. I don't think you even read the question and just copied from the documentation blindly.